# How can I enter data in an array through a taxt file or excel table in c# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

I am doing a school project and have 2 arrays the first array is the default array with which the program starts, the second is the array I use to store the new data after the program executes and then the NextGen array becomes the CurrentGen array. It's a 30x30 grid and the different numbers correspond to different colors. I was asked by the instructor to try and make it so that instead of changing the numbers in CurrentGen in the code, I make a text file or excel table in which it'll be easier to put the numbers in and when the program executes, it takes the data from said file and uses it in place of CurrentGen but I have never done something similar before. Can someone help me with it? I am writing in c# and am using WinForms.

```
public int[,] CurrentGen = new int[,] { {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,2,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                                         {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},};
        
        private int[,] NextGen = new int[30,30];
```

I tried looking for similar things online but nothing like what I am looking for comes up.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First off look into writing some code that can open and read a text file.

Comment: First off look into writing some code that can open and read a line of text in a text file e.g., "1,2,3". This is Comma Separated Value (CSV) format. Then add a loop that allows you to read more than one line. Process each line to extract the numbers between commas, convert them from text to int and place them in your array. Each line can be one row in your `CurrentGen` array. Note that C# supports collection classes that are expandable at runtime.

Comment: If the values in the array can be rendered as a single character, consider having your text file as having 30-character (or whatever the width is), where spaces represent zeros and the non-space values as values (that you parse).  Then read in the lines, pre-processing them into your array.  That way, the text file, when displayed with a mono-spaced font (say in Notepad) will look like an image (kinda-sorta).  You could have your first line look like `12345678901234...` to help you line things up (and you'd read that line in and ignore it)

Comment: If my opinion is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

Reading txt data to excel has given valuable comments in the comment area. According to your description, I wrote a piece of code that can read excel data and store it into a two-dimensional array of int type. Please correct me if my understanding is incorrect:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using DataTable = System.Data.DataTable;

namespace readExcel
{
 public class program
 {
     static void Main()
     {
         //You want to read the path of excel
         string path = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\11.xlsx";

         DataTable dt = ImportExcelToDataTable2(path);

         int[,] NextGen = new int[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];
         //string[,] array = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];
         for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
             {
                 NextGen[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][j]);
             }
         }
     }


     public static DataTable ImportExcelToDataTable2(string path)
     {
         //Note: Think of an excel file as a database, and a sheet as a table. Syntax "SELECT * FROM [sheet1] &quot;, the form should use &quot; [ ] &quot; and &quot; ]&quot;, the form should use &quot;[]&quot; and &quot;]", the form should use "[]" and ""
         //The following two ways can realize Access database
         //string conStr = string.Format(“Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;”, path);
         string conStr = "Provider = Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + path + "; Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 2'";
         using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
         {
             conn. Open();
             // Obtain relevant information of all Sheets (the following 2 ways can be achieved)
             //DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
             DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
             if (dtSheet. Rows. Count > 0)
             {
                 // Get the name of the first Sheet
                 string sheetName = dtSheet.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim();
                 string sql = string.Format("select * from[{0}]", sheetName);
                 using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                 {
                     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                     oda. Fill(dt);
                     return dt;
                 }
             }
             return null;
         }
     }
 }
```

}

At this time, the excel data has been stored in NextGen：

[image]